# AWS Athena Query to get EC2 instance Price from CUR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-cost-explorer

I'm trying to get the EC2 instance **price** - **for a specific EC2 instance** - using Amazon Athena + [CUR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cur/latest/userguide/what-is-cur.html)

The pipeline is already setup to run the SQL queries against CUR, but I'm having hardtime running a query which returns the actual cost for a specific EC2 instance - considering if it's on-demand/using savingPlans/ etc.

I'm looking at the [Data Dictionary doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cur/latest/userguide/data-dictionary.html), but that's not necessarily mapped to all the column names I retrieved from CUR/Athena query.

Specifically I'm having a hard time to map the result to a unique ID (e.g. EC2 instance ID, any tags, etc.) of the running instance.
(Found some examples [here](https://www.wellarchitectedlabs.com/cost/300_labs/300_cur_queries/queries/compute/#ec2-total-spend), but not for individual EC2 instances)

Any help on how to achieve this is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question, this is the query I came up with:

```
  line_item_resource_id,
  bill_payer_account_id,
  bill_billing_period_start_date,
  line_item_usage_account_id,
  DATE_FORMAT(line_item_usage_start_date,'%Y-%m') AS month_line_item_usage_start_date, 
  savings_plan_savings_plan_a_r_n,
  line_item_product_code,
  line_item_usage_type,
  SUM(line_item_usage_amount) AS sum_line_item_usage_amount,
  line_item_line_item_description,
  pricing_public_on_demand_rate,
  SUM(pricing_public_on_demand_cost) AS sum_pricing_public_on_demand_cost,
  savings_plan_savings_plan_rate,
  SUM(savings_plan_savings_plan_effective_cost) AS sum_savings_plan_savings_plan_effective_cost
FROM 
  "<CUR_DB>"
WHERE 
  year='<YEAR>' AND month='<MONTH>' 
  AND line_item_resource_id='<Instance-Id>'
  AND line_item_line_item_type LIKE 'SavingsPlanCoveredUsage'
GROUP BY 
  line_item_resource_id,
  bill_payer_account_id, 
  bill_billing_period_start_date, 
  line_item_usage_account_id, 
  DATE_FORMAT(line_item_usage_start_date,'%Y-%m'), 
  savings_plan_savings_plan_a_r_n, 
  line_item_product_code, 
  line_item_usage_type, 
  line_item_unblended_rate, 
  line_item_line_item_description, 
  pricing_public_on_demand_rate, 
  savings_plan_savings_plan_rate
ORDER BY 
  sum_pricing_public_on_demand_cost DESC;
```